# Simple query: mysql - very slow , mariadb - good performance

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, mariadb

Simple query:

```
select *
from data.staff AS staff
left join data.contact AS workphones on staff.id = workphones.staff_with_work_phone_id
```

Mysql run time: 5.3 sec.
MariaDb run time: 0.016 sec.

Contact has ~50000 rows.
Staff has ~600 rows.

What is the reason?
Is it possible to achieve the same result on mysql?

Thank you!

Explain MySql (v5.7.14):

```
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+--------------------------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------+---------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type | possible_keys                  | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  | filtered | Extra                                 |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+--------------------------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------+---------------------------------------+
| 1  | SIMPLE      | staff      | NULL       | ALL  | NULL                           | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 606   | 100.00   | NULL                                  |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+--------------------------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------+---------------------------------------+
| 2  | SIMPLE      | workphones | NULL       | ALL  | FK_2f7824065c2c4b0fbe5c00da271 | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 49180 | 100.00   | Using where.                          |
|    |             |            |            |      |                                |      |         |      |       |          | Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+--------------------------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------+---------------------------------------+
```

Explain MariaDB (v10.0.28):

```
+----+-------------+------------+------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+--------------------+-------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table      | type | possible_keys                  | key                            | key_len | ref                | rows  | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+------------+------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+--------------------+-------+----------+-------+
| 1  | SIMPLE      | staff      | ALL  |                                |                                |         |                    | 602   | 100.00   |       |
+----+-------------+------------+------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+--------------------+-------+----------+-------+
| 2  | SIMPLE      | workphones | ALL  | FK_1249f6bc1d68495090691f3ce02 | FK_1249f6bc1d68495090691f3ce02 | 9       | user_data.staff.id | 25476 | 100.00   |       |
+----+-------------+------------+------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+--------------------+-------+----------+-------+
```

The rest of the verification conditions are identical.
The test was conducted many times.

Comment: Which versions of these databases? Are they both properly tuned? Same hardware? Did you run the test multiple times to be sure the cache was warmed up? Are the servers both idle?

Comment: show the **EXPLAIN** from the query of both server

Comment: I added need info.

Comment: Which is the mysql engine? InnoDB or MyIsam ?

Comment: Used InnoDB....

Comment: Does it still take only 16ms when using `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...` ?  And please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

Comment: SQL_NO_CACHE hasn't changed any results

Comment: @Vladimir added an answer for "Simple query: mysql - very slow , mariadb - good performance"

Answer (score 1):

Your two query plans show you why MySQL is slower.
Both find the possible keys, which is a foreign key.

**MariaDB** will USE the FK: FK_1249f6bc1d68495090691f3ce02 is in both columns `possible_keys` AND `keys` in row 2.

**MySQL** does see the FK, but does NOT use it.
MySQL tells you, that it will use a

> Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)

in the `EXTRA` table.

MySQL does not use your Foreign Key.

**Foreign Key Joins**
Do you have an index on your foreign key in both database systems?
If only MariaDB has it, then you cannot blame MySQL, because it cannot use, what it does not have.